# Remove non-digit characters from random string except first occurrence of #

Tags: javascript, regex

This question looks trivial - but is not. I want using regexp to remove all non-digits characters from string without first `#` character. You can use below snippet (and edit `magic` function there) to tests:

```js
function magic(str) {
   // example hardcoded implementation - remove it and use proper regexp
   return str.replace(/#1234a5678b910/,'#12345678910');
}

// Test

tests = { // keys is input string, value is valid result for that input
    "#1234a5678b910": "#12345678910",
    "12#34a5678b910": "12#345678910",
    "1234a56#78b910": "123456#78910",
    "1234a5678b91#0": "1234567891#0",
    "1234a5678b91#0": "1234567891#0",
    "98#765a4321#039c": "98#7654321039",
    "98a765#4321#039c": "98765#4321039",
    "98a765b4321###39": "987654321#39",    
}

Object.keys(tests).map(k=> console.log(`${k} Test: ${(''+(magic(k)==tests[k])).padEnd(5,' ').toUpperCase()} ( result is ${magic(k)} - should be ${tests[k]})`) );
```

The input string is generated in random way.  I try this so far but no luck

```
function magic(str) {
   return str.replace(/(?<=#.*)[^0-9]/g, '') ;
}
```

Hot to do it using replace and regexp ?

Comment: `str.replace(/[^0-9#]|(?<=#.*)#/g, "");`

Comment: Try this: '#fklsjadklfsaklf4f4s5daf64s564fsa65fd46asf'.replace(/([#]?)([^0-9])+/g, '$1');

Comment: @Toto the 'duplicate' question inspired me to create this one - but - as its author clarify in comments - that question IS NOT duplicate - in that question OP wants to character # be at first place only - in this question the # can be in any place - an this totally change solution (and difficulty level)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable length lookbehinds only work in certain JavaScript engines (EMCA2018). See browser compatibility for lookbehind assertions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Browser_compatibility).

#### Regex method

For the engines that do support lookbehinds, you can use the following regex:

```
(?<!^[^#]*(?=#))\D+
```

Works as follows:

- `(?<!^[^#]*(?=#))` negative lookbehind ensuring the following does not match

  - `^` assert position at the start of the string
  - `[^#]*` match any character except `#` any number of times
  - `(?=#)` positive lookahead ensuring what follows is `#`
- `\D+` match any non-digit character one or more times

In simpler terms, `^[^#]*(?=#)` matches up to the position where the first `#` is encountered. We then negate these results (since we don't want to replace the first `#` in each string). And finally, we match the non-digit characters `\D+` that don't match those positions.

```js
function magic(str) {
   // example hardcoded implementation - remove it and use proper regexp
   return str.replace(/(?<!^[^#]*(?=#))\D+/g,'');
}

// Test

tests = { // keys is input string, value is valid result for that input
    "#1234a5678b910": "#12345678910",
    "12#34a5678b910": "12#345678910",
    "1234a56#78b910": "123456#78910",
    "1234a5678b91#0": "1234567891#0",
    "1234a5678b91#0": "1234567891#0",
    "98#765a4321#039c": "98#7654321039",
    "98a765#4321#039c": "98765#4321039",
    "98a765b4321###39": "987654321#39",    
}

Object.keys(tests).map(k=> console.log(`${k} Test: ${(''+(magic(k)==tests[k])).padEnd(5,' ').toUpperCase()} ( result is ${magic(k)} - should be ${tests[k]})`) );
```

---

#### String manipulation method

This method works best for cross-browser support (older browsers or those that don't currently support EMCA2018).

This uses two regular expressions to clean both substrings:

```
[^\d#]+    # replace all characters that aren't digits or # (first substring)
\D+        # replace all non-digit characters (second substring)
```

```js
function magic(str) {
   // example hardcoded implementation - remove it and use proper regexp
   i = str.indexOf('#') || 0
   x = str.substr(0,i+1)
   y = str.substr(i+1)
   r = x.replace(/[^\d#]+/g,'')+y.replace(/\D+/g,'')
   //console.log([i,x,y,r])
   return r
}

// Test

tests = { // keys is input string, value is valid result for that input
    "#1234a5678b910": "#12345678910",
    "12#34a5678b910": "12#345678910",
    "1234a56#78b910": "123456#78910",
    "1234a5678b91#0": "1234567891#0",
    "1234a5678b91#0": "1234567891#0",
    "98#765a4321#039c": "98#7654321039",
    "98a765#4321#039c": "98765#4321039",
    "98a765b4321###39": "987654321#39",    
}

Object.keys(tests).map(k=> console.log(`${k} Test: ${(''+(magic(k)==tests[k])).padEnd(5,' ').toUpperCase()} ( result is ${magic(k)} - should be ${tests[k]})`) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty easy - match the part including the first `#` (if any) and just replace non digits in the second group. Afterwards, just glue them together.

```js
function magic(str) {
    let rx = /^([^#\n]*\#)(.*)/;

    let string = str.replace(rx, function(m, g1, g2) {
        if (g1.endsWith("#")) {
            part1 = g1.replace(/\D+/g, "") + "#";
        } else {
            part1 = g1.replace(/\D+/g, "");
        }
        return part1 + g2.replace(/\D+/g, "");
    });
    return string;
}

// Test

tests = { // keys is input string, value is valid result for that input
    "#1234a5678b910": "#12345678910",
    "12#34a5678b910": "12#345678910",
    "1234a56#78b910": "123456#78910",
    "1234a5678b91#0": "1234567891#0",
    "1234a5678b91#0": "1234567891#0",
    "98#765a4321#039c": "98#7654321039",
    "98a765#4321#039c": "98765#4321039",
    "98a765b4321###39": "987654321#39",    
}

Object.keys(tests).map(k=> console.log(`${k} Test: ${(''+(magic(k)==tests[k])).padEnd(5,' ').toUpperCase()} ( result is ${magic(k)} - should be ${tests[k]})`) );
```

Comment: Almost works, see my second method (you also need to replace any non-digit character prior to the first `#`)

Comment: @ctwheels: You were right, added some programming logic. Will look into your's as well.

Comment: You can change your regex to `^([^#\n]*)(#)?(.*)` and return statement to `g1.replace(/\D+/g,'') + (g2||"") + g3.replace(/\D+/g, "");` and remove the `if` statement

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex to replace string `([a-zA-Z])|(?<=#(.*?))#`. This matches all character in `a-z` and in `A-Z` and `#` which are followed by another # and letters.

Comment: I Use - `str.replace(/([a-zA-Z])|(?<=#(.*?))#/,'');` - not pass tests from snippet :(